# Проблема с плагином mqpacker

Tags: gulp, postcss

Плагин mqpacker сортирует медиазапросы в неправильном порядке. **sort: true** стоит.

Сортирует он вот так:

@media (max-width: 768px) {
   ...
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
   ...
}

Хотя по идее должна быть нисходящая сортировка:

@media (max-width: 992px) {
   ...
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
   ...
}

Answer (score 1):

[Описание плагина](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-mqpacker).
Про опцию sort "Currently, this option only supports min-width queries with specific units (ch, em, ex, px, and rem). If you want to do more, you need to create your own sorting function ..."
Т.е. по умолчанию работает только с min-width